# Cannot deserialize instance of date from VALUE_STRING value None or request may be missing a required field at [line:1, column:131]

Tags: python, json, salesforce, etl, jsonparser

class_records = sf.query("SELECT Id FROM Staff_Assignment__c")
recs_to_delete = [{'Id': r['Id']} for r in class_records['records']]
recs_to_delete
sf.bulk.Staff_Assignment__c.delete(recs_to_delete)

for rec in staffass_data_records:

```
record = {}
record['ID_Class__c'] = rec['ID_Class__c']
record['ID_Staff__c'] = rec['ID_Staff__c']
record['Role__c'] = rec['Role__c']
if rec['Start_Date__c'] != None:
    record['Start_Date__c'] = str(rec['Start_Date__c'])
if rec['End_Date__c'] != None:
    record['End_Date__c'] = str(rec['End_Date__c'])

try:
    sf.Staff_Assignment__c.create(record)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Please post your code using the formatting
```
code
```

Comment: What is the actual payload being sent to Salesforce? Are the Date fields required? The error message is pointing clearly towards that as a problem.